# удалить фото ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте!
Есть ряд картинок (галерея), подскажите как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на картинку всплывал запрос на удаления и после одобрения - картинка УДАЛЯЛАСЬ с сервера. Сложность в том, что картинки лежат в разных подкаталогах `/images/h1/_.jpg` `/images/h2/_.jpg` и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, вам нужно:

1. Связать картинки на сервере и в галерее. Для этого можно использовать относительный путь к картинке на сервере, обычно он прописывается в атрибут [src](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img/src).
2. Сделать обработчик нажатия на картинку на JavaScript. Этот обработчик идентифицирует картинку и вызывает функцию удаления картинки. Предлагаю использовать [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) и [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/).
3. Сделать функцию удаления на JavaScript. Эта функция принимает идентификатор картинки и отправляет его на сервер с помощью асинхронного запроса (ajax). Опять же предлагаю использовать [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) и [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
4. Сделать сервис на сервере (php) который принимает идентификатор картинки и вызывает функцию удаления картинки.
5. Сделать функцию удаления картинки (php) на сервере которая принимает идентификатор картинки и удаляет её.

Comment: Спасибо за план! А можно на примере показать 2й и 3й пункт?

Comment: 2-3 пункт: $('.del').click(function (e) {
                var image = $(this).attr("src");
                var delete_var = 'act=delete_image&image='+image+''; //
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax.php",
                    data: delete_var,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('deleted');
                    }
                });
       });

Comment: 3-5 пункт ajax.php : <?php 
 if ($_POST['act'] == 'delete_image') {
$image = $_POST['image'];
        unlink($image);
    }
?>

Comment: чтото не работает

Comment: Ну всё верно! Как таковых проблем я не вижу. Предлагаю два пути решения:

Comment: 1. Отладить текущий вариант ajax+POST с помощью утилиты Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/apps). Для Windows - она устанавливается как расширение в Chrome. Выбираете тип запроса POST,указываете путь для запроса (/ajax.php), добавляете POST данные и тестируете только сервернуюю часть 4-5.
Если серверная часть работает и принимает запрос, то нужно разобраться будет с клиентской частью 2-3.

Comment: 2. Ещё вариант, перейти на запрос get (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) и данные передавать через него. Тогда JS код для отправки будет до безобразия прост:

$.get('/ajax.php,act=delete_image&image='+image'), function() {
  alert( "success" );
}).

Только не забудьте вместо $_POST['act'] использовать $_GET['act']

Этот запрос так же легко отладить в Postman

Comment: Получается в Postman нам нужно указать POST -> ссылку до скрипта на сервере, а далее в закладке Body -> fromdata -> вписать в значение ключа act=delete_image&image=images/aee8fb09.jpg  / Или не так делаю?!

Comment: Закладка headers - всё остальное правильно!

Comment: нашел решение, вопрос снят) ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!